# for the summer or during the summer

Tags: word-choice, difference

What is the difference of the meaning of these two sentences?

> 1. We usually go away **for** the summer.
> 2. We usually go away **during** the summer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the difference is that "for" implies the whole duration, and "during" implies a period within the larger period. For example:

> We usually go away for the summer.

Would be taken to mean that for the entire summer period, the speaker would be away from home, presumably on holiday. Whereas:

> We usually go away during the summer.

Would be taken to mean that at some unspecified time during the summer, the speaker would be away from home for some (currently unspecified) duration, but not for the whole of the summer period.

Comment: A good example of the difference would be "We're going to my daughter's for the Christmas holidays" implies that the speaker will be away for at least two days whereas "We're having a party during the Christmas holidays" merely implies a few hours somehere in the same period.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations. Now I understand the differences.